# importing packages and design pattern DAO

Tags: java, design-patterns, jdbc

I am really trying to learn correct ways to access databases that practice security and readable design principles.

First I am having a weird issues importing the packages I need. Below is my App class that I am just trying to run at the moment to make sure everything works and I can connect to a database before I code at further.

```
package application;

import dataBase.MySQLDataBaseDAO;
import establishConnection;  //error

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MySQLDataBaseDAO database;
    new DataBaseConnection();//naturally error a too
}

}
```

Here are just a snippet of the packages I am attempting to import.

```
package dataBase;

import java.util.List;

public class MySQLDataBaseDAO {


MySQLDataBaseDAO(){

}

void insert(Person person) {

}

void find(Person person) {

}
```

This class will create a GUI using dependency injection and ask the user for the username and password and connect to the database.

```
package establishConnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class DataBaseConnection {

private Connection conn = null;
private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee";
private String userName = "";
private String passWord = "";

DataBaseConnection() {
    connect();
}
```

If I was not clear my questions are:
1) How is my import wrong? I want to call the constructor from a class that is in a different package.
2) How does my design look. I did not post the whole code because I did not wnat to annoy anyone with a long post.

Comment: `import establishConnection.*;`

Comment: I do not see any "design" in your code. You just create an object in main...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App initialization should look something like this:

```
package application;

import dataBase.DataBaseDAO;
import dataBase.MySQLDataBaseDAO;
import establishConnection.DataBaseConnection;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataBaseConnection connection = new DataBaseConnection();
        DataBaseDAO databaseDao = new MySQLDataBaseDAO(connection);
    }
}
```

And your MySqlDataBaseDAO needs a database connection.

```
package dataBase;

import establishConnection.DataBaseConnection;

public class MySQLDataBaseDAO extends DataBaseDAO {
    private DataBaseConnection connection;

    public MySQLDataBaseDAO(DataBaseConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void insert(Person person) { }

    public void find(Person person) { }
}
```

Lastly, it should `extend` an interface named `DataBaseDAO`.

package dataBase;

```
public interface DataBaseDAO {
    public void insert(Person person);
    public void find(Person person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to import all classes of a package you have to use this:

```
import establishConnection.*;
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone!!! I was pretty shocked on how fast I got a response. I got it working and once again, thanks again. However I feel pretty dumb for not seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to import just a `class` and you are importing **entire** `package` (and not defining which class) that's why it raises an error.

try

```
import establishConnection.DataBaseConnection;
```

instead of

```
import establishConnection;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Only a type can be imported. establishConnection resolves to a package.

I hope you ll be seeing this error because you are supposed to import a type or *

Use `import establishConnection.*;` or `import establishConnection.<your class>`;

If you are using eclipse - use Ctrl+Shift+O which will organise the imports for you